# Understanding xmlns: what are the links linked to?

Tags: ros, urdf, xml, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read similar question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/251816/what-is-xmlns-tag-for-xacro/) ,but It still hasn't answered my confusions.

I refer to this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDF)

here's the snipper:

```
<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
   xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
   xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
   xmlns:xacro="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
   name="pr2" >
```

I know that XMLNS is namespace for XML

Quoting gvdhorn's commend on the thread I linked,

> "xmlns is short for "XML NameSpace", and is
> a special XML construct that is
> expained in the links @VictorLamoine
> posted. @shawnysh: you can essentially
> consider them like import statements
> in the example you posted. But it's
> really an XML thing, not ROS specific"

Please help to clarify these things:

1. What is the link specified in xmlns linked to? Is this link like a library (implying from gvdhorn's statement)? but why do we need the library?
2. If I am to create my own robot. How is the xmlns somehow involved in the creation?
3. How do i know which link to be linked to?
4. In the [tutorial code](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDF) after specifying the namespace above, could you give examples which lines of code are being appended by the namespace?

Please elaborate

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269235/understanding-xmlns:-what-are-the-links-linked-to?/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are looking at out-of-date URDF files. The current Gazebo documentation says you don't want those additional Gazebo namespaces, just the Xacro namespace (if you're using Xacro): [Tutorial: Using a URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros)

For your questions:

1. The URL in the xmlns attribute is not required to be a location that responds to an HTTP request. Instead, it is just a unique moniker identifying the namespace. You can use an XML catalog or the "xsi:schemaLocation" attribute to create a mapping between namespaces and the actual location of the schemas.
2. No, your robot specification in URDF does not need new namespaces for your robot. See the tutorial mentioned above, and [the general URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials).
3. N/A
4. Adding a namespace does not add anything to the XML file, but it allows **you** to add additional elements from the schema corresponding to that namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0